# Is there a way to check if a float is an integer?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python but I was wondering if there is a way to check if a float is an integer e.g if the float = 9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.

```
x = 9.0
if x.is_integer():
    print("It's an int!")
else:
    print("It's not what we wanted.")
```

Comment: do I put what I want to happen in the brackets?  `if x.is_integer()`

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer for you. :-)